# Is it possible to export a program created with the animation node as a python script?

Tags: python, animation-nodes

Is it possible to export a program created with the animation node as a python script?

I would like to convert an animation node into a python script.

I am not familiar with Python script, so I would like to do it automatically if possible, but you can do it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animation Nodes provide operators that provides the execution code of the current node tree. You can find that operator under the *Developer* panel, by pressing the *Write* button, the execution code of the selected node tree is written to a text block called `Execution Code`. For instance, the following node tree:

[image: Example Node Tree]

Have an execution code:

```
import numpy, sys, bpy
import itertools
from time import perf_counter as getCurrentTime
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Quaternion, Euler
AN = animation_nodes = sys.modules.get('animation_nodes')
from animation_nodes.data_structures import *
from animation_nodes import algorithms

nodes = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeTree'].nodes
_y52bwsmno0e080h = nodes['Random Vector']
_csk7p8pg5vv2v5d = nodes['Vector Math']
_8aspl5k05rbhwxn = nodes['Separate Vector']
_seed_y520 = _y52bwsmno0e080h.inputs[0].getValue()
_scale_y521 = _y52bwsmno0e080h.inputs[1].getValue()



# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Random Vector'
_seed = _seed_y520 + 25642 * _y52bwsmno0e080h.nodeSeed
_randomVector_y522 = algorithms.random.getRandom3DVector(_seed, _scale_y521)

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Vector Math'
_result_csk1 = Vector((abs(_randomVector_y522[0]), abs(_randomVector_y522[1]), abs(_randomVector_y522[2])))

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Separate Vector'
_x_8as1 = _result_csk1[0]

# Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Viewer'
_38xn88352kup1e3.execute(_x_8as1)
```

Notice that variables like `_seed_y520` and `_scale_y521` needs to be substituted with the seed and scale of the *Random Vector* node respectively.

Another example, a subprograms like this group:

[image: Example Subprogram]

Have an execution code:

```
import math, numpy, sys, bpy
import itertools
from time import perf_counter as getCurrentTime
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Quaternion, Euler
AN = animation_nodes = sys.modules.get('animation_nodes')
from animation_nodes.data_structures import *
from animation_nodes import algorithms

nodes = bpy.data.node_groups['NodeTree'].nodes
_o7ggcrgv1v0zeqz = nodes['Group Input']
_71b912e7wlqq8tj = nodes['Float Math']
_uyl54rvlbgh0b0p = nodes['Group Output']
_b_71b1 = _71b912e7wlqq8tj.inputs[1].getValue()
__socket_False_1_uyl = None



def main(group_input_0):
    global _b_71b1

    # Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Float Math'
    _result_71b2 = group_input_0 + _b_71b1


    return _result_71b2
```

The output code will not work out of the box as you might expect it, it depends on the `animation_nodes` module, functions defined by subprograms as well as values defined in the node tree interface.